# KeyNotFoundException during create region in Shell.xaml

Tags: wpf, prism

I just started with PRISM, and encounter a exception I can't resolve.

```
<Window x:Class="Workplace.Shell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:prism="http://www.codeplex.com/prism"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Grid>
        <Grid Name="Header" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="Header">

        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

.

```
using Autofac;
using Prism.Autofac;
using Prism.Modularity;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace Workplace
{
    class Bootstrapper : AutofacBootstrapper
    {
        protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
        {
            return new Shell();
        }

        protected override void InitializeShell()
        {
            base.InitializeShell();

            Application.Current.MainWindow = (Window) this.Shell;
            Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
        }

        protected override void ConfigureModuleCatalog()
        {
            base.ConfigureModuleCatalog();
        }
    }
}
```

After run I get exception:

> KeyNotFoundException: The IRegionAdapter for the type
>   System.Windows.Controls.Grid is not registered in the region adapter
>   mappings. You can register an IRegionAdapter for this control by
>   overriding the ConfigureRegionAdapterMappings method in the
>   bootstrapper.

Okey but `AutofacBootstrapper` class doesn't have any metod named `ConfigureRegionAdapterMappings` to override.

First I think something is wrong with `AutofacBootstrapper`, but even if I change it to `UnityBootstrapper` problem still exist. However second one allow me to override `ConfigureRegionAdapterMappings`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `Grid` isn't a useful host for a region. Try using a `ContentControl` instead.

Of course, you can create and register a custom region adapter if you absolutely want to use the `Grid`, but I cannot really see any benefit.

Comment: Okey problem solved. Now it's obvious for me why `Grid` is inadequate to define region, it doesn't inherits from `ContentControl`. Hard beginnings,  thanks a lot. :D

Comment: Now I get it, PRISM has built-in adapters(ContentControlRegionAdapter, SelectorRegionAdapter, ItemsControlRegionAdapter) which can adapt some `Controls` to be a region, more: https://prismlibrary.github.io/docs/wpf/Composing-the-UI.html#default-region-functionality. Like you mention I can write my own adpater but it's meaningless.